# British shipping forecast boundary shapefile

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

Does anyone have access to a shapefile containing British shipping forecast boundaries? I can see a shapefile on the [ESRI website](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=859436be603c4abb88382e49967ff180) but I cannot download it and have not been able to contact the owner of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have a shapefile but I can't find it any longer - I created it by hand using the coordinates given at http://www.users.zetnet.co.uk/tempusfugit/marine/area_coord.htm and a UK coastal outline.

Comment: Thanks Ian, this is perfect! Much appreciated. If I manage to create the shapefile myself I'll post it here. Thanks again.